# Why does my homemade hemp milk smell like sulfur?

Tags: vegan, dairy-free

I made some hemp milk in my Joyoung the other day, and it smells like sulfur. It doesn't taste bad, but the smell is a little off-putting. Is this normal? Have I let my hemp seeds go bad? Should I filter it better?

Comment: I'm not familiar with hemp milk, but I'd test the seeds... Do your hemp seeds smell rancid if you just crush a few to release the oils? Smell is one of the ways our bodies determine whether or not food is safe to eat, so when in doubt, trust your nose.

Answer (score 2):

HempNut Cookbook, by Richard Rose & Brigitte Mars, 2004 Green Press Initiative, page 21:
"Shelled hempseed also is high in minerals such as ... sulfur, ...: ... Sulfur helps the body resist bacterial invasion and protects it against toxic substances."